# Is there a way to indent and outdent lines without moving the cursor?

Tags: key-bindings, indentation

I often escape insert mode only to change the current line's indent by pressing `>>` or `<<` and then immediately go back to writing.
I wanted to make this easier, so I included these lines on my config:

```
inoremap <tab> <esc>>>a
inoremap <S-tab> <esc><<a
```

But, for some reason, whenever you `<<` or `>>`, Vim moves the cursor to the start of the line as if you had pressed `^`.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is determined by the ['startofline'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'startofline') option. Set it to off, if you don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!
`<C-t>` and `<C-d>` are used to indent and outdent from insert mode.

This snippet creates the behavior I was looking for:

```
inoremap <tab> <C-t>
inoremap <S-tab> <C-d>
```

Comment: Thanks @exvx, add those lines to your .vimrc file. That did it for me.